# How to declare variable in VB.NET running on Terminal Services Server (Windows 2008 Server)?

Tags: vb.net, terminal-services

I have a VB.NET application running on a terminal server (Windows 2008 Server).

In the login form I use:

Public bGrantAccess As Boolean = False

If the variable is set to true after validation this will happen for all terminal server users, not only for the specific user. This means when user A has logged in and user B, C, D, etc. are automatically logged in.

How should variables be declared when running the application on a terminal server so they are user specific?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sessions with unique values in order to seperate the users.

Comment: Can you please help me a little bit more with how to do this?

Comment: Well when user a logs in, create a session variable Session("UserId") = A etc. Then when User B logs in you create Session("UserId") = B and so on. If a public variable is boolean and set to true it will be true for all.